# Overcoming type erasure in Scala in cases of different return types

Tags: scala, generics, type-erasure

I want to define the following two Scala functions:

```
def Pr(
  f: Int => Int,
  g: Tuple3[Int, Int, Int] => Int
): Tuple2[Int, Int] => Int = {
  def recurse(x: Int, counter: Int): Int = counter match {
    case 0 => f(x)
    case y => g(x, y-1, recurse(x, y-1))
  }
  (recurse _).tupled
}

def Pr(
  f: Tuple2[Int, Int] => Int,
  g: Tuple4[Int, Int, Int, Int] => Int
): Tuple3[Int, Int, Int] => Int = {
  def recurse(x1: Int, x2: Int, counter: Int): Int = counter match {
    case 0 => f(x1, x2)
    case y => g(x1, x2, y-1, recurse(x1, x2, y-1))
  }
  (recurse _).tupled
}
```

The basic idea here is that if `f` is n-ary and `g` is (n+2)-ary, then `Pr(f,g)` is (n+1)-ary.  The problem, of course, is type erasure.  After type erasure `f` and `g` are both `Function1`'s, and the two `Pr` functions are indistinguishable.  I thought creating a single `Pr` function with type tags might help here, but I'm not sure how to make the return type change in each case.

Open to any suggestions; ones that can solve this without making use of additional libraries (Shapeless, Scalaz) are preferred.

Comment: You _could_ use the magnet pattern here, but don't. Just give them different names.

Comment: (Side note: 95% of the time type erasure is your friend. If it makes something impossible, that's probably a bad thing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the other 5%, the standard idiom (that predates magnetization) is to add a dummy implicit parameter list:

```
def Pr(
  f: Tuple2[Int, Int] => Int,
  g: Tuple4[Int, Int, Int, Int] => Int
)(implicit dummy: DummyImplicit): Tuple3[Int, Int, Int] => Int = {
  def recurse(x1: Int, x2: Int, counter: Int): Int = counter match {
    case 0 => f(x1, x2)
    case y => g(x1, x2, y-1, recurse(x1, x2, y-1))
  }
  (recurse _).tupled
}
```

There's surely a gazillion Q&As about that.

Scala overloading only considers the first param list; the dummy param is to disambiguate the erased signature.

This is modulo overloading is evil and Travis Brown, whose blog is about doing impossible things in Scala you probably shouldn't do, says it's probably not a good thing. Full disclosure, tl;dr.